# .htaccess to WP_Rewrite regex pattern

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a re-write rule in .htaccess (it's working fine) that I'd like to add as WordPress wp_rewrite -
mainly for portability and user's convenience... The question is just how the regex-pattern has to look like...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/services/rest/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ wp-content/plugins/some_plugin/api.php?action=$3 [L,NC]
```

The syntax that I would require looks about like this:

```
$newrules = array('^/services/rest/(.*)' => mAPI_PLUGIN_URL.'/socket.php?action=$matches[1]');
```

Any suggestions how to solve or how to improve that?

Comment: You say it's working fine, so what's the problem exactly? Please clarify your question.

Comment: The .htaccess is working fine (1st code snippet) - I'm looking for the WP rewrite syntax (2nd code snippet)... for referral: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code in your script/theme:

```
add_action('init', 'add_rewrite_rule');
add_filter('query_vars', 'query_vars');
add_filter('wp_head', 'rooter');

function add_rewrite_rule()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('services/rest/(.*)', 'index.php?my_action=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

function query_vars($query_vars)
{
    $query_vars[] = 'my_action';
    return $query_vars;
}

function rooter()
{        
    if(get_query_var('my_action'))
    {
        // Do your tasks here
    }
}
```

In my case it is working good for a plugin I have developed for personal use.

Comment: Meanwhile I came to the conclusion that this probably isn't even possible by design: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30386/where-do-i-use-add-rewrite-rule ... because I require NOT to re-write through index.php (basically need a path exlcluded and the last part of it as query parameter).

Comment: WordPress is single entry point application, and that's why you have to use the index.php.

From within the router you can load the file you like to run, pass to that the variable and do all operations.

Finaly, you can add a die() in some place into the script that you like to run in ordeer to don't display the home page. Also you can do anything you like with that file, such us add your own HTML and so on

Comment: I understand what you mean, but in this case it's not really an advance to use WP's router - b/c it's a 100% back-end script (performance). Even if it's not that "user-friendly" - I'll stick with .htaccess ... still can add a replacement .htaccess file to the install routine.

Comment: But still, your answer is correct - despite the fact that one can only rewrite everything to the same entry point...